# My computer running Ubuntu crashed and doesn't remember my login password

Tags: login, password, crash, reset

My computer crashed and doesn't remember my login password. I have already tried resetting my password the way where you go in to grub but that didn't work. I would be happy with any solution even if it involved completely resetting the computer and losing all files. Also I am not too familiar with the terminal so explain things.

Comment: *"doesn't remember"* *"doesn't work"* please try to describe exactly what happens, including any error messages that occur. What where you doing when the crash occurred - were updates in progress?

Comment: What is your username? As @steeldriver said, what were you doing when the crash occured? Do you have an Ubuntu Live media (CD/DVD/USB/SD, the same you used to install)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use grub to choose one of the recovery options, this should give you a root terminal. (This is from memory! So might not be correct)

if you're root then the prompt should end with a # so you don't need to use `sudo`.

To verify that you can change the users/passwords etc type `cat /etc/passwd` if this shows a list of usernames then you should be able to run the command `passwd <username>` which will prompt for a new password. If you don't get `cat` to show anything you will need to look up how to mount the root partition in recovery mode

You might have to look at `usermod` & `useradd` if you want to create a new user to login with. 
If you do create a new user, run `sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>` so that user can use sudo

*Think I'll go familiarise myself with recovery while you try that..*

Comment: Yes this works. Changing the password didn't work but creating a new user did.

Answer (score 0):

Does answering my question close the discussion? Going to the grub menu and selecting recovery mode and then going to root allowed me to get back on with "useradd "

Comment: *Does answering my question close the discussion* Accepting your answer will indicate that it is solved, nevertheless if will be answerable in future.